# Plotting a graph of tangent function returns a straight line instead

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to plot a graph of tangent function, but it appears as a straight line instead. What is the error? Why does it not compile?

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=-4:7] [scale=0.8]
    \draw[ultra thick, ->] (-4,0) -- (7.5,0) node[right] {$\textbf{X}$};
    \draw[ultra thick,->] (0,-2) -- (0,4.2) node[above] {$\textbf{Y}$};
    \draw[dashed, thick,red] (1.57,0) -- (1.57,1);
    \draw[dashed, thick,red] (4.71,0) -- (4.71,1);
    \draw[dashed, thick,red] (-1.57,0) -- (-1.57,1);
    \draw[ultra thick,color=blue]   plot [samples =100](\x,tan(\x r)) node[right] {$y = \tan~x$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you need to include the tan bit in braces, like `{tan(\x r)}`. To quote section 22.5 of the tikz/pgf manual: _Note that you will often have to put the x- or y-coordinate inside braces, namely whenever you use an
expression involving a parenthesis._

Comment: David Robertson, Sorry, I did, but it doesn't work

Comment: The problem is the domain and the singularity of the tan - function at `\pi/2`

Comment: I know this is 4 years later, but for people who might be reading along: It took me a while to realise that the trig functions take a **degree input** rather than a *radian input.* So rather than specifying your domain as `-pi:pi`, go for `-80:80` (don't go for a full `90` because `tan(90)` blows up to infinity). And then I also divided my `\x` by 90 in the plot: `plot ({\t/90},{tan(\t)})` – so that 1 unit is equal to π/2 radians.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Piece of cake with `pgfplots`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-4.3,xmax=7.8,ymin=-4.5,ymax=4.5,
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$}
    ]
  \addplot[blue,samples=200] {tan(deg(x))}node[right]{$y=\tan x$};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

The problem seems to be the fact that tan takes on arbitrarily large values near its asymptotes. To get around this, I broke the domain into four pieces, and drew each one using a loop.

[image: Attempted solution]

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
\draw[ultra thick, ->] (-4,0) -- (7.5,0) node[right] {$\textbf{X}$};
\draw[ultra thick,->] (0,-2) -- (0,4.2) node[above] {$\textbf{Y}$};

\foreach \i in {-1, 0, 1, 2}{
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\start}{\i*pi-1.3}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\left}  {(\i-0.5)*pi}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\end}  {\i*pi+1.3}
    \draw[dashed, thick,red] (\left,-3) -- (\left,3); 
    \draw[ultra thick, color=blue] plot [domain=\start:\end, samples=25] (\x, {tan(\x r)} );
}
\node[blue, right] at (8, 2) {$y = \tan(x)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

You should include the `{tan(\x r)}` between two braces and specify the domain `-pi/2 < x < pi/2` taking care of infinities near the `|pi/2|`. This is not the best way to draw a function like this, but I just corrected the error you requested. The way that @HarishKumar solved it is the way I would use.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=-4:7] [scale=0.8]
\draw[ultra thick, ->] (-4,0) -- (7.5,0) node[right] {$\textbf{X}$};
\draw[ultra thick,->] (0,-2) -- (0,4.2) node[above] {$\textbf{Y}$};
\draw[dashed, thick,red] (1.57,0) -- (1.57,1);
\draw[dashed, thick,red] (4.71,0) -- (4.71,1);
\draw[dashed, thick,red] (-1.57,0) -- (-1.57,1);
\draw[ultra thick,color=blue] plot[domain=-.4*pi:.4*pi] (\x,{tan(\x r)}) node[right] {$y=\tan x$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This part `[domain=-4:7] [scale=0.8]` is wrong since it cannot handle two option blocks unlike the `path` parsing.

You need parentheses around tangent because otherwise it thinks the expression is finished on the first parentheses as David Robertson quoted.

Also the line you are seeing is the top of the diverging plot because the domain is too large and that's TikZ trying to fit the graph on a page hence pushing the rest out of the page.

Instead use pgfplots

Answer (score 1):

I just changed @AboAmmar response a little bit. Hope it helps

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=-4:7] [scale=0.8]
% x and y axes
\draw[thick, ->] (-6,0)     -- (6,0)   node[right] {$x$};
\draw[thick, ->] (0,-4.2)   -- (0,4.2) node[above] {$y$};
% vertical asymptotes
\draw[dashed, thick,red] (pi/2,-4.2)    --  (pi/2,4.2);
\draw[dashed, thick,red] (3*pi/2,-4.2)  --  (3*pi/2,4.2);
\draw[dashed, thick,red] (-pi/2,-4.2)   --  (-pi/2, 4.2);
\draw[dashed, thick,red] (-3*pi/2,-4.2) --  (-3*pi/2, 4.2);
% tangent between vertical asymptotes
\draw[ultra thick,color=red, <->] plot [domain=-0.425*pi:0.425*pi] (\x,{tan(\x r)});
\draw[ultra thick,color=red, <->] plot [domain= 0.573*pi:1.425*pi] (\x,{tan(\x r)});
\draw[ultra thick,color=red, <->] plot [domain= -1.425*pi:-0.573*pi] (\x,{tan(\x r)});
% x tick labels
\node[below right] at (-3*pi/2, 0)  {$-\frac{3\pi}{2}$};
\node[below right] at (-pi, 0)      {$-\pi$};
\node[below right] at (-pi/2, 0)    {$-\frac{\pi}{2}$};
\node[below right] at (0, 0)        {$0$};
\node[below right] at (pi/2, 0)     {$\frac{\pi}{2}$};
\node[below right] at (pi, 0)       {$\pi$};
\node[below right] at (3*pi/2, 0)   {$\frac{3\pi}{2}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

here what you should get:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-plot,amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(2,2)
  \psset{xunit=0.7cm,yunit=0.7cm}
  \psaxes[ticks=none,labels=none]{<->}(0,0)(-4,-5)(7,5)
  \psplot[linecolor=blue,linewidth=0.03,plotpoints=2500]{-1.38}{1.38}{x RadtoDeg tan}
  \psplot[linecolor=blue,linewidth=0.03,plotpoints=2500]{1.76}{4.52}{x RadtoDeg tan}
  \psplot[linecolor=blue,linewidth=0.03,plotpoints=2500]{4.9}{6.28}{x RadtoDeg tan}
  \psplot[linecolor=blue,linewidth=0.03,plotpoints=2500]{-3.14}{-1.76}{x RadtoDeg tan}
  \psline[linestyle=dashed,linewidth=0.03](-1.57,-5.3)(-1.57,5.3)
  \psline[linestyle=dashed,linewidth=0.03](1.57,-5.3)(1.57,5.3)
  \psline[linestyle=dashed,linewidth=0.03](4.71,-5.3)(4.71,5.3)
  \put(5,0){$X$}
  \put(-3.4,0){$X\prime$}
  \put(0,3.6){$Y$}
  \put(0,-4){$Y\prime$}
  \put(-2.2,0){\circle*{0.16}}
  \put(-1.1,0){\circle*{0.16}}
  \put(0,0){\circle*{0.16}}
  \put(2.2,0){\circle*{0.16}}
  \put(1.1,0){\circle*{0.16}}
  \put(3.3,0){\circle*{0.16}}
  \put(4.4,0){\circle*{0.16}}
  \put(0,1.4){\circle*{0.16}}
  \put(0,-1.4){\circle*{0.16}}
  \put(0,2.8){\circle*{0.16}}
  \put(0,-2.8){\circle*{0.16}}
  \put(0,0.7){\circle*{0.16}}
  \put(0,-0.7){\circle*{0.16}}
  \put(0,2.1){\circle*{0.16}}
  \put(0,-2.1){\circle*{0.16}}
  \put(-2.5,.3) {$-\pi$}
  \put(2.3,-.3) {$\pi$}
  \put(4.3,.3) {$2\pi$}
  \put(3.3,.3) {$\frac{3\pi}{2}$}
  \put(1.1,.3) {$\frac{\pi}{2}$}
  \put(-1.8,-.4) {$-\frac{\pi}{2}$}
  \put(-0.4,0.7){$1$}
  \put(-0.4,1.4){$2$}
  \put(0.2,-0.7){$-1$}
  \put(0.2,-1.4){$-2$}
  \put(-1,-4.5){\large \boldmath{$y=\tan x$}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a new option in `addplot` namely `restrict y to domain`. It is very minimalistic and prevents the tangent from exploding and thus solves the line problem:

```latex
\addplot[mark=none, color=blue, ultra thick, restrict y to domain=-5:5] {tan(deg(x))}
```

Here is the full code:

```latex
\begin{figure}[ht] \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle, xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}, domain=-pi/2 + 0.01:pi/2 - 0.01, samples=200, legend style={at={(1.1,0.35)}, anchor=north east,},]
         \addplot[mark=none, color=blue, ultra thick, restrict y to domain=-5:5] {tan(deg(x))};
         \addlegendentry{$\tan(x)$};
    \end{axis}    
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

A less elegant solution would be to set `ymax` and `ymin`.